# Binary search over an "infinite" sequence. Where do I start?

Tags: python, language-agnostic, binary-search

I have an interesting problem. I'm faced with a function that takes a long time to compute a value based on some index. Call it `takes_a_long_time(index)`. The values returned from this function are guaranteed to have a global minimum, but there are no guarantees that the index associated with will be close to zero.

Since `takes_a_long_time` takes arbitrarily large positive integers as its index, There are unique constraints on how to begin the binary search. I need a way to create a finite interval to search in for the exact minimum. My first thought was to check increasingly large intervals starting from zero. Something like:

```
def find_interval_with_minimum():
    start = 0
    end = 1
    interval_size = 1
    minimum_in_interval = check_minimum_in(start, end)
    while not minimum_in_interval:
        interval_size = interval_size * 2
        start = end
        end = start + interval_size
        minimum_in_interval = check_minimum_in(start, end)
    return start, end
```

This would seem to work fine, but there is an additional detail that really throws things off. `takes_a_long_time` requires exponentially more time to compute a value as indexes approach zero. Since `check_minimum_in` would require multiple calls to `takes_a_long_time`, I would like to avoid starting at zero.

So my question is, given that the minimum could be anywhere on [0, +infinity), is there any reasonable way to run this "backwards?" Or, is there some good heuristic to use to avoid checking low indices if not necessary?

I'd love a language agnostic solution. However, I am writing this in Python, so if there is a python specific approach to this, I'd take that as well.

Comment: "is there some good heuristic" obviously depends on your problem domain.

Comment: Is the function smooth/convex?  Are you guaranteed that there are no local minimums?  Normally I'd suggest a one sided binary search with repeated doubling to find the upper bound, but the exp time for low indicies seems nasty.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel That might be phrased poorly. I'm more looking for a simple heuristic that I could adapt. Like, the equivalent of start at the middle, but for an infinite sequence.

Comment: @rrenaud the curve is smooth, with a single (global) minimum. The one sided doubling is what I tried to express in that pseudo code, but yes, the exp time is what gets me.

Comment: Is there a maximum?  That is, is there a last element of the sequence?

Comment: Do you know the limit of the function as the index approaches infinity?

Comment: your function may take arbitrarily large positive integers but, maybe, in practice you have some estimation about how large those integers would be. Can't you use that as an upper limit and start there?

Comment: @Michael J. Barber the limit is positive infinity.

Comment: @F.C. Unfortunately, I'll be dealing with degenerate cases occasionally. That being said, it doesn't preclude me from picking something large and working in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments to the question, the curve is well-behaved and you could use something like [ternary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search). The only problem then is how to handle the inconvenient behavior as your approach zero. So don't start at zero: define a new function `g` from your function `f` with `g(x) = f(1/x)`. Search this starting from `x=0` and a small value, doubling or otherwise increasing the interval size until it contains the minimum.

To do this, you need to know the limit of `f` as its argument approaches infinity, or the equivalent limit of `g` as its argument goes to zero. If it can't be evaluated explicitly, I'd try a numerical approximation.

See the comments to the answer for some points to consider in how you increase the interval size, especially that by Steve Jessop.

Comment: Is doubling the right strategy? Since time to compute `f` increases "exponentially ... as indexes approach zero", it may be that calculating `g(x)` takes time exponential in `x`. So maybe we should increase more slowly. If we limit the overshoot to a constant, we get a Theta(2^(n+constant)) term in the complexity, where `n` is the index we're looking for. If we overshoot by a geometric progression it's Theta(2^(constant*n)), which is even more catastrophically slow than 2^n.

Comment: I like the strategy of using f(1/x). Especially including the analysis by @Steve Jessop.

Comment: @Steve Jessop It's hard to say. We don't know how close to zero is the trouble region where the computation time increases exponentially. Outside the trouble region, we should increase the interval fast. Inside, it's ugly: we can exponentially increase the cost of evaluation or go slowly to reduce the worst case, but exponentially increase the number of (exponentially expensive) evaluations. Depending on the function, it may be feasible to predict the proper increase with Richardson extrapolation or the like. The ugly behavior of this problem makes it downright fascinating, I think.

Comment: Better to use Golden-Section search than ternary search as it requires less evaluations.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the thing to do is to pick a large number, big enough that `takes_a_long_time` doesn't take too long to be acceptable. Start two threads: one which starts looking up towards positive infinity for a range containing the minimum, and another one which starts looking down towards zero for a range containing the minimum. Because of the exponential time increase, 0 might as well be at infinity as far as searching is concerned. Whichever thread finds a result, cancel the other one.

But then, unless you want to take advantage of multiple CPU cores don't start two threads (and if you do, don't start exactly two threads, start one per core or so). Just alternate doing work on on side or the other.

Given this basic strategy, now you need to tune the rate at which you approach 0. The faster you approach it, the fewer steps to find the minimum if it's really on that side, but the bigger the range left to be binary searched, because on average you'll "overshoot" further towards zero. If the performance curve is reciprocal-exponential, then presumably you want to overshoot as little as possible, so should approach 0 very slowly. It might even be that your task is computationally infeasible, "exponential" often means "impossible".

Obviously I can't say anything about what the initial "large number" should be. Is a hundred tolerable? Is a million? Graham's number? If you don't even know what's likely to have acceptable performance, you could find out by running in parallel (again, either via threads or via dovetailing) a set of calculations of `takes_a_long_time` for different indexes until one of them completes. Again, there's no guarantee that this is computationally feasible - if every single index that fits in the memory of your computer takes at least a billion years, you're stuck in practice even though you have a solution in theory.

Comment: In the majority of cases calculating `takes_a_long_time` will terminate for low values. However, degenerate cases can really only be found (as far as I know) to be degenerate by running them. For this reason, I appreciate the suggestion to try a few indices at once and see if they terminate. That being said, I'm only going to try this if Michael's answer doesn't work out. Python's GIL and everything.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes in Python for "threads" read "processes". I don't know much (or anything) about performance multi-threading in Python. Python generators do provide a fairly natural means to dovetail, though, providing you can modify the code of the slow function. If you litter it with `yield None` every million loop iterations or whatever, then you can create a bunch of generators and then keep calling `next()` on each one in turn until one of them gives you a result rather than None.